# JSpinner when set SpinnerNumberModel,(range 0, 999),can not delete number when value below 10

Tags: swing, jspinner

following code :

```
 SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 999, 1);
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
JFormattedTextField  textField = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
```

why can not delete text value when only **one-digit?**

has any way to fix it ?

Comment: CXSpinner is not a standard Swing component and we don't know what is does. Post a [mre] demonstrating your problem using a `JSpinner`. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code posted. So your code needs a JFrame with the JSpinner added to the frame.